# Setting html site

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

so I have an asp.NET website I've developed. I bought a domain and a host service. I went to the host services and uploaded all the files.

Problem: the start page has to be `index.html/htm` (which is located in root directory/httpdocs) but visual studio doesn't create a `index.html` file, so i made one myself. Thing is I cant redirect to any other files, I don't know the path. I've tried:

```
- "mywebsite.com/otherfile.aspx" but it says file not found. 
- "mywebsite.com/httpdocs/otherfile.aspx" file not found. 
- "/otherfile.aspx" file not found.
- "~/otherfile.aspx" file not found.
```

can anyone think of how I could access this file? I've never setup a website :(

Comment: can you please check folder permission.Right on folder and check folder permission.set 777 to all folders

Comment: I cant, im uploading the files via a plesk plataform and i can only enter directories or upload files, no right clicks. :/

Comment: ohhh...when you rnter directories you can check what is the folder permission?

Comment: there isn't any folder "permission" if that's what you are saying, if thats not what you mean, i cant access any type of configuration for any file or folder, i can Upload, copy, move, delete thats it.

Comment: can you please share your site link here?

Comment: the site is empty...

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that your hosting provider supports .Net?  Httpdocs and Plesk sound like a Linux server that is not configured to server .aspx files.